# No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to Objective-C and have been trying to work with UITableView. Here is the method where I get the error:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableViewCell *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
}
```

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Try to use Xcode's autocomplete feature to enter such method names. It will help avoid typos like this.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method signature is wrong and should be

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you see error messages like that, you should look for the type of the variable to which you send the message.

In this case, the problem is that you have mistyped the signature of the method: the first parameter type is `UITableView`, not `UITableViewCell`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableViewCell *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This should be

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```